# Why Flux can use "class" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flux

Code is from here: https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/c62ad1e76f00b880df8e55b00aa9296b627e0ab7/src/Dispatcher.js#L111:

```
class Dispatcher {
  constructor() {
    this._callbacks = {};
    this._isPending = {};
...
```

What kind of syntax here it is using? As far as I know, "class" is a key work in Javascript 2.0, which is not supported by many browsers. Why here it is used? Is it working?

Comment: "Class" isn't an ECMAScript [*key word*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1), it's a [*future reserved word*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2). ;-) And since ECMA-262 ed 6 is one possible future, it has [*Classes*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions). For the moment at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching the flux Gulp file answers your question.

```
gulp.task('lib', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.js')
             .pipe(gReact({harmony: true}))
             .pipe(gReplace(/__DEV__/g, 'false'))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));

});
```

Here, gReact stand for `var gReact = require('gulp-react')` fun fact, that there's a missing semicolon here in the sorce file :)

On npm at https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-react

```
react(options)

options.harmony

Type: boolean
Default: false

Enable harmony features for JSX.
```

So i guess gulp will make some kind of transform steps from ES.next code to ES.current upon build.

Comment: Correct! The real job is done by this visitor: https://github.com/facebook/jstransform/blob/master/visitors/es6-class-visitors.js